# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1: "Unsupported get request."

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am running the Facebook SDK 3.1 on Xcode 4.5.1 with iOS6 on an iPhone 4S. I have an access token, can see my friends, i have not tried to build any other Graph Requests, However, every time I initialise the Facebook object, I see this printed to my console:

```
Error: HTTP status code: 400
```

So I decided to NSLog the generated 'error' and got the following:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xb89020 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            message = "Unsupported get request.";
            type = GraphMethodException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

I have researched this alot and found out that the Application automatically tries to run a 'publishInstall' request that gets logged on your Facebook Developer console.

I am also unsure how to interpret this error, is it possible that Facebook has placed a limit on this type of request?

I've been seeing alot of other people struggling with this type of issue hand have not yet come across a solution for it as it seems like a recent change to the facebook api.

Nonetheless, I would appreciate any advice that can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: 'Unsupported Get Request' means you tried to access an ID or endpoint that has blocked you / is deleted / is invisible / has privacy restrictions / doesn't exist - is it possible the app is in sandbox mode and you're trying to use it as a non-developer or something like that?

Comment: I have put the app in sandbox mode and the error is generated before any "Login" action is requested. I am sure it has to do with the new Mobile App Installs 'Insights' metric or [publishInstall]. This is a new addition to the Facebook iOS 3.1 SDK and have only had one App install successfully logged.

Comment: Are you trying to use the app as a non-admin of the app? if so, don't, or take it out of sandbox mode - it should be OK

Comment: Ok Thanks @Igy , I took it out of Sandbox mode, it works now without error.

Comment: That makes sense, in sandbox mode a lot of privacy checks will hide the app, making API calls to retrieve the app's details, perform login, etc, fail for non-admins